# Outlook 2010 Macro to save attachment and FTP it to web server

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook, ms-office, office-2010

This is the first time i've tried anything like this and having a few issues.

i've written the code below which is a Outlook 2010 Macro. It Saves a selected email details in an SQL database, saves any attachements locally and then attempts to upload them via FTP.

It looks as if it's attempting to upload as a command window opens, but then quickly closes again but the files haven't been uploaded and I don't get any error information.

Can anyone see any issues with my code?

```
Sub ExportToSql()
Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsMsgs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmdMsgs As New ADODB.Command
Dim strDBFile As String
Dim sql As String
Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=IP_ADDRESS;initial catalog=DB_NAME;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;"
objConn.Open

Set objExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
If objExp.Selection.Count > 0 Then
    If objExp.Selection(1).Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then
        For Each objMsg In objExp.Selection

            cmdMsgs.ActiveConnection = objConn
            cmdMsgs.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Email] ([Date], [Subject], [From], [To], [Body]) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            cmdMsgs.Parameters.Append cmdMsgs.CreateParameter("param1", adDBTime, adParamInput, -1, objMsg.SentOn)
            cmdMsgs.Parameters.Append cmdMsgs.CreateParameter("param2", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, 1000, objMsg.Subject)
            cmdMsgs.Parameters.Append cmdMsgs.CreateParameter("param3", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, objMsg.SenderEmailAddress)
            cmdMsgs.Parameters.Append cmdMsgs.CreateParameter("param4", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, objMsg.To)
            cmdMsgs.Parameters.Append cmdMsgs.CreateParameter("param5", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, 50000, objMsg.Body)
            cmdMsgs.Execute

            For Each objAtt In objMsg.Attachments

                'save file locally
                Dim saveFolder As String
                Dim filePath As String
                saveFolder = "C:\Users\jw"
                filePath = saveFolder & "\" & objAtt
                objAtt.SaveAsFile filePath
                Set objAtt = Nothing



                'upload saved file
                Dim vPath As String
                Dim vFile As String
                Dim vFTPServ As String
                vPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WEBSITE\attachments"
                vFTPServ = "IPADDRESS"
                fNum = FreeFile()
                Open filePath For Output As #fNum
                Print #fNum, "USERNAME PASSWORD"
                Print #fNum, "bin" ' bin or ascii file type to send
                Print #fNum, "put " & filePath
                Print #fNum, "close" ' close connection
                Print #fNum, "quit" ' Quit ftp program
                Close
                Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & " " & vFTPServ, vbNormalNoFocus

            Next
        Next
    End If
End If

    objConn.Close
    Set rsMsgs = Nothing
    Set objConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.
J.

Comment: How are you checking for errors?  Do you get a copy of the contents of the command window saved somewhere?

Comment: Add this to the end of your shell command  `& "> FTPOutput.txt"`, to redirect the output of the FTP program to a text file so you can read what error, if any, FTP might be returning.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, can't get the out put file to work, tried a few different ways: Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & " " & vFTPServ & "> C:\Users\jw\FTPOutput.txt", vbNormalNoFocus??

Answer (score 0):

I think username and password should be on two separate lines. Also, use ">>" instead of ">" to output the FTP command results to a text file.